# Are there any video players for Windows that can play at different speeds?

Tags: windows, media-player

When I was an undergrad I used to watch videos of lectures on tape.  The library had these cool videos that let you watch at double speed.  The voice would be high pitched, but I was able to get through them a lot faster.  These days are long gone because everything is digitized.  Is there any way to watch videos at double speed, including the audio, on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can do this.  Look for the "Faster" option under the Playback menu.  And unlike those old lecture tapes, VLC will adjust the pitch for you, too.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Media Player can do it as well:

[image: Context Menu of Windows Media PLayer, highlighting the “Play speed settings” item with a mouse pointer]

[image: Play speed settings window]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that [Cyberlink PowerDVD](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd/overview_en_US.html) can handle what you want.